# How to root Android with Samsung Odin

Tags: applications, rooting

How to root A Samsung mobile phone or tablet using Samsung Odin?

Answer (score 1):

Android rooting is not an uncommon term using tech nerds anymore. It is very common and everybody at least heard the term. So why we do this? As my opinion, we already have enough control over our device. Don't you think? that's how the less than half of the population of the Android community keep their devices without unstable it. But the other half sees the situation completely different. They root their devices to flash new ROMs, gain more control by customizing download unauthorized apps and modifying default functions in the system. So to do this you have o [download rooting tool](https://odindownload.com/root-android/) that most suitable for your device. For a Samsung user, it is not any software other than Samsung Odin. So let's talk about how to root with Odin.

[image]

**What is Samsung Odin**

It is a free utility that serving a wide range of devices and specially created for the Samsung devices by Samsung itself. With the time the software is updated so you can see there are several versions for the same tool. Select the best one for your device is your responsibility. This one-click rooting method is not like traditional root tools available out there. The flow starts with flashes the root package and then root it through the computer. And do not waste your time for searching direct rooting methods for Samsung Odin, because there isn't.

**Compatible list**

As I mentioned earlier there are different versions of Odin for the different operating system. So check the list below and select the suitable version for your device.

- v. 1.85 - GingerBread and Ice Cream Sandwich
- v. 3.09 -  Jellybean and KitKat
- v. 3.10.7 - Lollipop
- v. 3.11.1 - Marshmallows
- v. 3.13.1 - more latest versions

[image]

**Android rooting with Samsung Odin**

*Preparation*

- Samsung Odin is only compatible with windows. So install necessary
  drivers to the PC and make it ready.
- It's not hurt be ready to whatever happens. So backup all of the
  mobile phone for more security.
- Enable USB debugging on the device. (Settings --> about --> Build
  number --> Tap 5 times --> You are a developer now --> USB debugging
  --> enable)
- The process could not be continued. So keep a sufficient battery
  power.

*Let's start the process of Android rooting*

1. Go to [this site](https://autoroot.chainfire.eu/) and download the suitable root package. Check your device name, model number, Android version, and build number beforehand.
2. Now extract the downloaded package in a new folder.
3. Power off the device and boot it into download mode. To do this press and hold  Power Key, Home Key, and Volume Down Key simultaneously.
4. Open the Odin file in the extracted folder.
5. Connect the mobile device with the PC using a USB cable.
6. The software will automatically detect the device you will see "Added" in the lower left panel
7. Click the "AP/PDA" button and select the extracted file.
8. Then click "Start" button
9. Now the rooting will start. After it completes you will see the message "PASS"
10. The device will be rebooted for one last time. There will be [SuperSu](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.supersu&hl=en) installed already on the device if the root was a success.

**Wrap up*
Odin is an application specifically created for Samsung smartphones and tablets. But it does not say it limited to that brand. It can serve various brands like HTC, LG, etc.*